# How do I create a "back" button on a View Controller that was initiated from a UITab Bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

How do I create a "back" button on a View Controller that was initiated from a UITab Bar?

I am initiating the View Controller form the UI Tab Controller. How do I add a back button?

[image]

Comment: where exactly the back button should be ?

Comment: Top left like the default

Comment: If you want it at the top left, what is the screen shot of the tab bar at the bottom supposed to tell us?

Comment: This is an iOS question, not a Swift question. The language is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "don't". Apples HIG (Human Interface Guidelines) say that when you use a tab bar controller, it should be the top-level navigational control of your app.

You could have one of the tabs contain a navigation controller, and that child view controller could have a navigation bar that includes a back button, but you should not have the tab bar controller be a child of a navigation controller.

If you wanted to violate Apples HIG and make the root level view controller be a navigation controller that contained a tab bar controller you could do that but it would make for a confusing interface. You'd make the root view controller of your app a navigation controller. Then one of the view controllers you pushed onto that navigation controller would be a tab bar controller. When you pressed the back button the navigation controller would pop that navigation controller off the stack and leave you with whatever view controller was under the tab bar controller.